# angular directive template not printing any text

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

I have just started learning Angular and trying to print some text through angular custom directive. but nothing is getting print. Please help me out. Here is the index.html and script.js file.

```js
angular.module('main', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        
            $scope.name = "firoz";


        })

        .directive('myDir', function () {
                                
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                template: '<div>Trying to print this text</div>'
            };
                                
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.17" data-semver="1.3.17" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <mydir></mydir>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the Plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/ub9Ch34OtckzQuCI9sDk?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hyphenate anywhere that has a capital when used in the directive, like:

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct Angular syntax is:

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
```

```js
angular.module('main', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        
            $scope.name = "firoz";


        })

        .directive('myDir', function () {
                                
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                template: '<div>Trying to print this text</div>'
            };
                                
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.17" data-semver="1.3.17" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <my-dir></my-dir>
  </body>

</html>
```